# Subir archivo JSON a azure blob storage

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-storage

tengo un archivo json que se genera con este codigo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionStringSisman))
        {
            string procedureName = "RPT_GET_DATA_MAQUINA_FORMATO_JSON";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parametro", valor);

                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            row.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows, Formatting.Indented);
                    //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reader, Formatting.Indented);

                    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Reportes\Archivos JSON\rptMaquinas.json", json);

                    //BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString1);
                    //BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

                    //BlobClient blob = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("YourBlobName");

                    //using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
                    //{
                    //    blob.UploadAsync(ms);
                    //}
                }
            }
        }

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(jsonFilePath, "rptMaquinas.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString1, containerName);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var filePathOverCloud = file.Replace(jsonFilePath, string.Empty);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file)))
            {
                containerClient.UploadBlob(filePathOverCloud, stream);
                Console.WriteLine(filePathOverCloud + "Uploaded!");
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

El problema que tengo es a la hora de querer subirlo a un contenedor de un blob en azure , trate de subirlo con un memorystream que vi en algunos ejemplos pero no me funciono o talvez no estoy usando el ejemplo de forma correcta, tambien intente subirlo como un archivo  como se puede ver en la ultima parte del codigo, pero esto hace que me pida algunas librerias que ya no se pueden encontrar.

estoy trabajando en consola net framework 4.8, alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor

gracias de antemano